# Including thumbnail captions in RSS feed

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rss, caption

Do you know the best way to incorporate the function `the_post_thumbnail_caption` into a function that gets thumbnail posts for the RSS feed? I am working on a project that requires having captions of thumbnail images populating on an RSS feed and appreciate your time shared on this inquiry.

In other words, I would like to include `get_the_post_thumbnail_caption` function in this:

```
function featuredtoRSS($content) {
global $post;
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
$content = '<div>' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'medium', array( 'style' => 'margin-bottom: 15px;' ) ) . '</div>' . $content;
}
return $content;
}
```

Would is be best to use the `&&` operator?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve what I was trying to do, if anyone is trying to add captions from thumbnails to their RSS feed all you need to do is add get_the_post_thumbnail_caption like this:

```
function featuredtoRSS($content) {
global $post;
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
$content = '<div>' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'medium', array( 'style' => 'margin-bottom: 15px;' ) ) . '</div>' . $content;
$content = '<div>' . get_the_post_thumbnail_caption( $post->ID  ) . '</div>' . $content;
 }
 return $content;
  }
```

Please chime in if there is a more effective way to do this, I am always looking for better practices!